# Time series (stochastic process) estimating parameters using characteristic function

Tags: time-series, stochastic-calculus

I have a time series of assets ${A_1, A_2, ..., A_n}$, which is described by a sophisticated distribution having the following characteristic function:  $\phi(u; t;\theta)$, where $\theta$ is a vector of unknown parameters. 
I need to esimate vector of unknown parameters $\theta$ of characteristic function.

I tried to find a PDF using the inverse Fourier transform to use the maximum likelihood method, but the characteristic function is too complicated for that.
I also thought about building the empirical characteristic function using the time series of assets and to estimate parameters using the least square method, but I do not know how to build the empirical characteristic function, because time series is not just a sample of random variables, it is a random process that depends on time.

Comment: Is this question about *Mathematica* the software, or a general mathematics question?

Comment: It is a general question, but I'm triyng to solve it using Mathematica.

Comment: Could you add a specific small example, possibly a simplified version of your actual problem ?

Comment: Also asked on math.se: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602898/time-series-stochastic-process-estimating-parameters-using-characteristic-func